# Python: How to create a 16 character long digest using hashlib.md5 algorithm?

Tags: python, md5, hashlib

[Php's md5 function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) takes an optional second argument which, if true, returns a smaller hash of length 16 instead of the normal 32 character long hash.

How can we do the same using python's `hashlib.md5`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*"an optional second argument which, if true, returns a smaller hash of length 16 instead of the normal 32 character long hash."*

This is not true: The second parameter [`$raw_output`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) specifies whether the output should be [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) (hex) encoded or in a raw [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) string. The hash length does not change but rather the length of the encoded string.

```
import hashlib

digest = hashlib.md5("asdf").digest() # 16 byte binary
hexdigest = hashlib.md5("asdf").hexdigest() # 32 character hexadecimal
```

The first should only be used inside your code and not presented to the user as it will contain unprintable characters. That's why you should always use the `hexdigest` function if you want to present the hash to a user.

Answer (score 6):

A note for those trying to get the hash in Python 3:

Because Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing with `hashlib` and because strings in Python 3 are Unicode by default (unlike Python 2), you'll need to encode the string using the `.encode` method. Using the example above, and assuming utf-8 encoding:

```
import hashlib

digest = hashlib.md5("asdf".encode("utf-8")).digest() # 16 byte binary
hexdigest = hashlib.md5("asdf".encode("utf-8")).hexdigest() # 32 character hexadecimal
```